# Best practices for Azure configuration?

Tags: configuration, azure

So when we started our Azure migration we migrated our `web.config` settings over to the Azure configuration `.cscfg` file.

While this works, and is jolly useful in test environments as I can quickly hack the configuration, this seems rather dangerous in production... as I can quickly hack the configuration.

More formally, it means that it's easy for anyone with access to the Azure management console to make uncontrolled changes to a production Azure instance.

This strikes me as very bad.

So is there in practice any utility behind the `.cscfg` file beyond the standard diagnostic string configuration and so forth?

Comment: So who are you letting in on the Azure Management Console, then? I'd expect that to be a safe place...

Comment: The idea of _any_ uncontrolled changes to my configuration makes me a bit concerned. Even if we carefully control access to the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We like the flexibility of .cscfg files in testing, and we don't want to have a slightly different codebase for testing vs. production because we believe our testing environment should be an exact replica of the production environment...minus a few config differences.

At the same time, we're paranoid about some developer accidentally deleting the wrong deployment or changing the wrong .cscfg file/value.  To solve this problem, we created two subscriptions, one for testing and one for production.  We give all developers access to the testing subscription, but only those who are responsible for deployment have access to the production subscription.

The deployment engineers know exactly what they can and cannot do in a production environment (rebooting/reimaging instances, deleting deployments, etc.).  They know that the ONLY .cscfg value to be touched in production is the "Instances count" property (our build server sets all other production .cscfg values).

So far, this setup has worked quite well for us.

Comment: This is what we do too.  For SOX compliance (or whatever other compliance, idk), developers can't have access to prod or prod configuration.  Which also means we have to have a single config to hand off to the env team to deploy with the software.  A nice single cscfg file make that an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your security & compliance policies, you may want to have a custom app-settings solution to house all your app-settings in perhaps Azure storage or SQL Azure...

There is nothing extra "recommended" but it is extremely useful to have the app settings be available for change w/o redeployment...

For ease of switching between environments in Visual Studio, check out a blog entry that I've recently published @ http://www.paraleap.com/blog/post/Managing-environments-in-a-distributed-Azure-or-other-cloud-based-NET-solution.aspx

Comment: > it is extremely useful to have the app settings be available for change w/o redeployment... < Only in test environments. I really don't want it to be even possible for uncontrolled changes to go to live. If we need to tweak settings in test, I'm quite happy to do a Remote Desktop and hack `web.config`...

Answer (score 0):

You can still use web.config in Azure for configuration-stuff that you want to keep not-so-configurable. We combine the two...

Not-so-configurable in this case, means you'll need to redeploy to change them...

Comment: I'm looking for guidance on what's "not-so-configurable" - what would you consider?

Comment: Ah... Guidance... Hard to find... :) Whatever it is that makes you concerned and isn't a problem to not be able to re-configure. We have our databaseconnectionstrings and send-email-and-sms configurations in there (.cscfg) and nothing else...

Comment: ...you might also want to be able to enable/disable tracing/logging in there. (.cscfg again...)

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem can really be used by just limiting the access to Azure Management Console. If there are several people that need to be able to deploy you can just create certificates for the to use instead of giving them access to Azure Management Console.

We actually have our build environment reconfigure our configuration files when we deploy to production. That basically eliminates the need of ever going into the management UI and the configuration always ends up the same.